# Delete specific logs from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have logs saved in elastic search and I want to delete logs that have a @timestamp field in May 2015 - all logs prior to this are ok.

I saved the following code in a file called 'delete.conf'

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_query' -d '

{
    "range" : {
        "@timestamp" : { "from" : "2015-05-01 00:00:01", "to" : "2015-05-09 11:59:59"}
    }
}'
```

I run this file in logstash using the following command:

```
logstash -f delete.conf
```

The results were like so ...

```
UOD-220076:bin student$ logstash -f delete.conf
Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) after 
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.
```

I have checked and re-checked but can't get what's wrong with my code.
In addition, would this be the 'correct' way to accomplish the deletion ?

Comment: This is a curl command that talks to elasticsearch. You can directly execute this from your Unix command-line , no need to use logstash to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash configuration files cannot contain any arbitrary commands. They have a specific layout which looks like this (more info [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html)):

```
input {
    ...
}
filter {
    ...
}
output {
    ...
}
```

If you want to execute your curl command in a shell, it won't work either because your query is missing the `query` part, it should look like this:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_query' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : { "gte" : "2015-05-01 00:00:01", "lte" : "2015-05-09 11:59:59"}
        }
    }
}'
```

Note that `from/to` in a `range` query are deprecated in favor of `gt/gte` and `lt/lte`.

Finally, if you want to delete all logs in May 2015, I would suggest setting the end date to `2015-05-31 23:59:59` instead.

Comment: Thanks Val - but i'm still getting an error, pasted below.                                                                                 Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) after 
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.

Comment: There is no need to use logstash for this. You should just run the curl command in your shell. Please try again and let me know.

Comment: Val, my code now looks like this .............curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_query' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : { "gte" : "01/05/2015:00:00:00", "lte" : "30/05/2015:11:59:59"}
        # "@timestamp" : { "gte" : "May 1st 2015, 00:00:01", "lte" : "May 9th 2015, 00:01:00"}
        }
    }
}'                           And the results now look like this  ............org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [logstash-2015.04.29] Failed to parse
 at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java

Comment: From what I can see your dates are not formatted properly. But you should update your question with your latest code as it's not really legible in this comment and the error doesn't appear in full. Let me know.